# Dropdown in Ruby on Rails: show some other fields, buttons... depending on the selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a view. The view has a dropdown menu and i want to add other fields to the view, depending on the index i selected in the dropdown.

http://abload.de/image.php?img=unbenanntcajcc.png

at ... i want to show other stuff like textfields. (i'm using bootstrap for styling)
thats the code:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<div style="height: 452px; overflow: auto">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Select a Filter <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">First name</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Last name</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Occupation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Location: Birth</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Location: Marriage</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Location: Death</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Location: Burial</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Time: Birth</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Time: Marriage</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Time: Death</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Time: Burial</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Relatives </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br />
    ...
    <br />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">+</button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Add filter</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You may need front-end tech, such as JavaScript to handle the dynamic parts.

Comment: That's right.  Place the elements that appear after the select action in hidden divs, and un-hide them with a javascript action attached to the select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this:

add classes to your different anchor tags in the dropdown menu like so:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li><a class="firstname" href="#">First name</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="stuffIwanttoadd"></div>
```

Then in a javascript file have something like:

```
$("a.firstname").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("div.stuffIwanttoadd").innerHTML="<p>Here is some stuff I want to add</p>";
    });
```

and do that for each element of the list (you should wrap the javascript in a function to make this easier).

EDIT: to get the javascript to run you'll need to attach it to the page, this means registering it in a `window.onpageload` event (or something like that) assuming you are using turbolinks you're going to want to do that like this:

```
var initFunc = function() {
  // everything you want to attach to the dom goes in initFunc
  $("a.firstname").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("div.stuffIwanttoadd").innerHTML="<p>Here is some stuff I want to add</p>";
    });
  };
$(document).ready(initFunc);
$(window).bind('page:change', initFunc);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I changed my code. javascript is completely new to me, so i just copied your js code and pasted it in a new js-file in ./app/assets/javascripts. 
but the <p> text does not appear if i click on firstname. are there more steps i should do? sorry, i'm completely new to web-dev.